# Как в Kotlin внутренний анонимный класс преобразовать в лямбда-выражение?

Tags: kotlin, лямбда-выражение

Есть интерфейс Operation, вот его код:

```
interface Operation {
    fun getResult(param1: Double, param2: Double): Double
}
```

В MainActivity создаём внутренний анонимный класс:

```
var operation: Operation = object : Operation {
       override fun getResult(param1: Double, param2: Double): Double {
            return param1*param2
       }
   }
```

И затем выводим в консоль значение, которое возвращает метод getResult():

```
println("${operation.getResult(2.0, 2.0)}")
```

Можно ли вместо анонимного класса использовать лямбда-выражение, и если да, то как это будет выглядеть в коде?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java интерфейсы обрабатываются автоматом, а вот для интерфейсов. объявленных в Kotlin, нужна специальная пометка `fun`

Как пример:

```kotlin
fun interface Operation {
    fun getResult(param1: Double, param2: Double): Double
}
```

Студия должна после этого изменения автоматом предложить превратить объект в лямбду примерно такого вида:

```kotlin
var operation = Operation { param1, param2 -> param1*param2 }
```

Ссылка на документацию, где можно почитать чуть подробнее про функциональные интерфейсы [туть](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/fun-interfaces.html)

Comment: Всю голову сломал, а дело было всего-лишь в пометке fun в сигнатуре интерфейса)) Спасибо большое!